# Count number of elements in each dimension in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Lets say I have a tensor `y` with shape `(batch_size, n)` which contains integers. I am seeking a *tensorflow* function that creates two new tensors from input `y`.

The first return value `w1` should have shape `(batch_size, n)` and contain at  position `b,i`, one over the number of times the integer in `y[b,i]` occurs in `y[b]`. If `y[b,i]` is zero, then also `w1[b,i]=0`.  Example:

The second return value `w2` should simply contain one over the number of different integers (except for 0) in each batch (or row) of `y`.

```
y=np.array([[ 0,  0, 10, 10, 24, 24],  [99,  0,  0, 12, 12, 12]])
w1,w2= get_w(y)
#w1=[[0 , 0 , 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],  [1, 0, 0, 0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333]]
#w2=[0.5,0.5]
```

So, how can I get tensorflow to do this?

Comment: How can the number of times the integer occurs be non integer ?

Comment: Sorry, I messed that up. It should be the inverse of the counts. I fixed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`tf.unique_with_counts`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique_with_counts):

```
y = tf.constant([[0,0,10,10,24,24],[99,0,0,12,12,12]], tf.int32)

out_g = []
out_c = []
#for each row
for w in tf.unstack(y,axis=0):
    # out gives unique elements in w 
    # idx gives index to the input w
    # count gives the count of each element of out in w
    out,idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(w)

    #inverse of total non zero elements in w
    non_zero_count = 1/tf.count_nonzero(out)

    # gather the inverse of non zero unique counts
    g = tf.cast(tf.gather(1/count,idx), tf.float32) * tf.cast(tf.sign(w), tf.float32)
    out_g.append(g)
    out_c.append(non_zero_count)
out_g = tf.stack(out_g)
out_c = tf.stack(out_c)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(out_g))
   print(sess.run(out_c))

#Output:

#[[0.   0.    0.5   0.5        0.5        0.5       ]
#[1.    0.    0.    0.33333334 0.33333334 0.33333334]]

# [0.5 0.5]
```